# How to make a textbox.text = combobox.text in "real time"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, combobox, textbox

I want a textbox.text = an invisible ComboBox.text in real time.

I can't figure what event I can use for this.

Everytime I try to mousewheel my Combobox items to change the ComboBox.text, the TextBox.text is showing the previous ComboBox.text... (like the n-1 ComboBox.text)

I'm pretty sure it's quite simple to solve but I can't figure it out...

EDIT on request :
I'm currently using this simple line in a specific ComboBox event :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
        
TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.Text

End Sub
```

But with this event (and I tried many others of the ComboBox), everytime I select a ComBoBox listitem (with click or mousewheel), I get this result [current textbox1.text] = [previous combobox1.text]

See a short clip of the problem here. (hard to describe)
[Short clip of the problem](https://streamable.com/axf90z)

In the clip, when the numbers are changing without any click, I simply mousewheel.

Comment: What code do you have so far, please [edit]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the swift answer. Done ! :)

Comment: Yiou shouold use sender instead of Combobox1.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted?view=net-5.0  Should be something like TextBox1.Text = senderComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

Comment: Hi jdweng and thanks again ! :-)

I'm trying to figure the exact correct VB.NET syntax of this solution tbh...

Comment: Well, it seems that ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() is working :-)

Thanks again for pointing this out jdweng !

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by jdweng :

Use this method instead of Combobox1.text

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I'm trying to make some maths :-)

Here is the code :

```
     Private Sub ComboBoxUnitsName_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxUnitsName.SelectionChangeCommitted
            Try
                TextBoxTotalCost.Text = (Decimal.Parse(ComboBoxUnitCost.SelectedItem.ToString()) * (Decimal.Parse(TextBoxUnitQty.Text.ToString())))
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
    
        End Sub
```

[Red square * red square = blue square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkNrl.png)

```
Red square 1 = TextBoxUnitQty
Red square 2 = ComboBoxUnitCost (with a SQL table fill)
Blue square = TextBoxTotalCost
```

And it's not working this way :-(

Comment: Nobody for the calculation ? :-(